# Undefined value for response.message in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, response

I'm trying to display response.message as content to a tag with id test. It's getting displayed as undefined.

```
    success:function(response){
        console.log("response"+response); // works
        var msg = response.message; 
        if(response.status=="success"){
            console.log("response1"+msg); 
             document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = msg; //undefined
        } else {
            jQuery('#test').contents(msg);
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = msg; //undefined
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your response actually look like?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton 
response{"status":"error","message":"Data not found"}

Comment: But you aren't parsing json in your code

Comment: Sure you got a tag HTML with an id named test? and is present in the page?

Comment: @headmax yep <p id='test'></p>. Anyway found the mistake added JSON.pare() function and it worked.

Comment: @akhil regonda Do you known why you need in this context JSON.parse() sending by a PHP page? i think because your ouput from this page didn't send a header formatted with json content. header("Content-type:application/json"); you needed before your echo json_encode($data);

Comment: Also is rather common to specify the datatype when setting up the jquery ajax request.

Comment: Am new to AJAX. Recently started learning it and thanks for the info @headmax

Comment: @akhil regonda Wecome ;) good night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I normally handle this is parsing the JSON response for it to be made into a JavaScript object (Using [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)), try this code below.

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log("response" + response);
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    var msg = response.message; // works
    if (response.status == "success") {
        console.log("response1" + msg); // prints/works
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = msg; //undefined
    } else {
        jQuery('#test').contents(msg);
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = msg; //undefined
    }
}
```

---

## Alternatives

You should also be able to set the content type on the PHP page itself before the output using headers

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
```

You can also set the datatype to json in your ajax call which is pretty standard

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        //process success
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: @akhilregonda You're welcome! I'm glad that I could help :)

Comment: Could you explain why this worked? `console.log("response1" + msg);`

Comment: @ficuscr Because a string of JSON is not a javascript object. Unless your speaking specifically about just the code snippet you said, I really have no idea. My answer is just from my own experiences and what has worked for me.

Comment: `console.log("response1" + msg);` worked *because it didn't.* unclear question is unclear.

Comment: So console output was "response1undefined"? and that "worked" per OP? Hi Kevin, where I'm confused...

Comment: No, from what I understood, `response` was _not_ undefined, rather `response.message` was undefined, because it wasn't a javascript object, it was just a string. @ficuscr

Comment: My bad console.log("response1" + msg); showed undefined. output in console was response1undefined. @ficuscr

Answer (score -1):

The undefined isn't msg, the undefined is probably being return from `document.getElementById('test')`.